# Add specific string to the end of specific lines from files

Tags: python, csv, addition, lines

So right now I have:

```
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

How do I use python to write to the file and make it:

```
1,A,some_string1
2,B,some_string2
3,C,some_string3
```

All I found was a solution to add the same string to every line like this:

```
1,A,abc
2,B,abc
3,C,abc
```

Using:

```
file_name = "thing"
string_to_add = "abc"

with open('thing', 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in   f.readlines()]

with open('thing', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

Comment: Should the random strings have a certain length?

Comment: Nope they can be anything

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with files of any size:

```
    import random

    with open('input.csv') as in_file:
        with open('out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            for in_line in in_file:
                in_line = in_line.strip()
                rand_line = random.randint(1,100)  # your random string
                out_file.write("{},{}\n".format(in_line, rand_line))
```

Comment: Can you explain why you open two different files?

Comment: There is no simple solution to modify the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

[`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) are the tools you are looking for:

```
import csv
import string
import random

with open('input.csv') as fin:
  with open('output.csv', 'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
      # random string of length 6 consisting of any upper/lower case ascii letters
      rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(6))
      writer.writerow(row + [rand_str])
```

Comment: Sorry didn't explain properly, when I said random_string I meant a string that I make not one that is generated via random module.